# Is it possible to display database sql by matching url slug?

Tags: mysql, url

I am new with php.
Let say I have url:

```
www.mysite.com/myslug-1
```

and I already have sql table :
[sample sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY892.jpg)
So, when its match, I get all the data to display in page

Is it possible to display database sql by matching url slug?
Please any help with simple of php script.

Comment: `mysql` and `sql-server`? Which?

Comment: im using mysql as database